# Eliminar Array especifico dentro de otro Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un Array global que guarda dentro mas arrays. Los arrays internos guardan dos valores, la x e y de la posicion de un grafico.

Bien pues, dicho esto os explico como funciona por ahora y lo que necesito.

Tengo (por ahora, en el futuro seran mas) dos checkbox, cuando estan activados guardo los datos a los que se menciona en la checkbox dentro del array padre. Estos datos son un Array con dos valores(como he dicho antes). Añadirlos no es problema, uso `push` y listo, el problema es eliminarlos cuando un checkbox se deseleciona.

Tengo este codigo:

```
//Checkbox para mostrar data eaepunt1
                $("#eae").change(function()
                {
                    mostrarDatos();
                });

                //Checkbox para mostrar data arabpunt1
                $("#arab").change(function()
                {
                    mostrarDatos();
                });


                function mostrarDatos(){
                    if($(eae).prop('checked') == true)
                    {   
                        totaldata.push(eaepunt1[coundata])                      
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Borrar los datos del checkbox
                    }

                    if($(arab).prop('checked') == true)
                    {
                        totaldata.push(arabpunt1[coundata])                     
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        //Borrar datos del checkbox
                    }
                    gr_html.series[0].data = totaldata;         
                    gr_html.redraw();                   

                }
```

En un principio se podria vaciar el Array padre y volverlo a llenar cada vez que ejecuto la funcion, pero me parece una solucion un poco "chapuzera". ¿Como deberia hacerlo?

Comment: en contraposicion a `push()` tienes `slice()` que borra elementos de un array indicandole la posicion donde quieres que empiece a cortar y el numero de elementos que quieres quitar

Comment: ya pero el problema es que la posicion de los elementos que elimino depende del orden en el pulse los check

Comment: creo que dentro de `mostrarDatos` no tienes referencia al objeto chequeado. Debiera ser, en cambio `if($('#arab').prop('checked') == true)` y `if($('#eae').prop('checked') == true)`. ¿Dónde se declaran totaldata, arabpunt1 y earpunt1? ¿De donde sale `countdata`?

Comment: Y eaepunt1 y arabpunt1 contienen otros arrays de dos posiciones que representarían la 'x' y la 'y' de cada punto no? entiendo entonces que earpunt1 y arabpunt1 representan cada uno, una serie de la gráfica no?

Comment: @Hictus Eso es, son una serie de coordenadas,

Comment: @amenadiel Ya, de las declaraciones en los ifs me he dado cuenta despues y lo se me ha olvidado cambiarlo, coundata es una variable numerica que determina que posicion de los array hijos tengo que coger. Totaldata es el array padre y arabpunt1 y earpunt1 son los array hijos

Comment: Pon un código que se pueda reproducir por favor, si no, estamos en adivinanzas y pura especulación.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía hombre pues no voy a poner 200 lineas que tiene el codigo porque entonces tendria mucha informacion inutil, enseño la funcion que me falla y explico de donde vienen las cosas.

Comment: ¿Crees que con eso se puede reproducir tu problema? Cuando se pregunta se trata de poner un ejemplo [completo, mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que pueda ser reproducido para observar el problema.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Pues si, no necesitas saber que programa estoy haciendo si la duda reside en una parte del codigo el cual se puede transladar y probar por tu cuenta con el simple hecho de poner dos variables con arrays con datos "x" e "y" y guardalos dentro de otro array vacio. Que seas incapaz de adaptar un html con 2 checkbox para probarlo por ti mismo no es mi culpa, la gente me ha dado respuestas porque no necesitas un ejemplo para entender como funcionan los arrays o la logica del programa, necesitas el codigo que estoy probando y una explicacion de como lo estoy haciendo para entenderlo.

Answer (score 1):

No veo problema en que hagas una copia de tu *array* original solo para redibujar tu gráfica, agregando los datos opcionales (determinados por los elementos *check*) a dicha copia.

Es decir:

```js
function mostrarDatos() {
    var salida = totaldata.slice();     // copia del arreglo original

    if ($(eae).prop('checked') == true) { 
        salida.push(eaepunt1[coundata]);
    }

    if ($(arab).prop('checked') == true) {
        salida.push(arabpunt1[coundata]);
    }

    gr_html.series[0].data = salida;
    gr_html.redraw();
}
```

De esa manera no tienes que estar "rastreando" cuáles elementos pertenecen a cuál *check* para poder eliminarlos de tu *array* original (algo que se complicaría agregando nuevos elementos opcionales).

Si necesitas dicho *array* completo para algo más, entonces puedes generar una nueva función *helper* que te ayude con eso; algo en estas líneas:

```js
function generarDatos() {
    var salida = totaldata.slice();

    if ($(eae).prop('checked') == true) { 
        salida.push(eaepunt1[coundata]);
    }

    if ($(arab).prop('checked') == true) {
        salida.push(arabpunt1[coundata]);
    }

    return salida;        
}

function mostrarDatos() {
    gr_html.series[0].data = generarDatos();
    gr_html.redraw();
}
```

La copia de un objeto tipo *array* no debe causar un *cuello de botella* (a menos que contenga un número de elementos muy alto); si quieres probar los distintos métodos para realizar copias, puedes [revisar este *benchmark*](http://jsben.ch/#/wQ9RU).

Comment: Es una buena solucion pero el problema es precisamente que voy a manejar una serie muy grande de datos.

Answer (score 0):

No se si he comprendido muy bien la pregunta, pero creo que con `slice` e `indexOf` lo podrias resolver.

```
function mostrarDatos(){
                    if($(this).prop('checked') == true)
                    {   
                        totaldata.push(eaepunt1[coundata])                      
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        totaldata.slice(totaldata.indexOf(eaepunt1[coundata]),1)
                    }

                    if($(this).prop('checked') == true)
                    {
                        totaldata.push(arabpunt1[coundata])                     
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        totaldata.slice(totaldata.indexOf(arabpunt1[coundata]),1)
                    }
                    gr_html.series[0].data = totaldata;         
                    gr_html.redraw();                   

                }
```

Un saludo!

Comment: No funciona, creo que es porque las posiciones en las que se encuentrar los arrays hijos dependen del orden en el que pulsas los check. Por ahora me funciona vaciando el arraypadre y cargandolo de nuevo cada vez que pulso. Pero como he dicho, mi solucion me parece un poco chapuzera.